# Uploading a file to a S3 Presigned URL

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rest-client

I'm trying to upload a local file to a S3 presigned URL. It should be really straight forward, but looks like I'm missing something.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

**Example:**

```
ENV['RESTCLIENT_LOG'] = "stdout"
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'rest_client'

s3_object_key = "folder-name/file.zip"

AWS.config(access_key_id: 'xxx', secret_access_key: 'xx')
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['my-bucket-name']
s3_object = bucket.objects[s3_object_key]

upload_url = s3_object.url_for(:put, expires: 100000).to_s

RestClient.put(upload_url, file: File.new("local-file.zip"))
```

**Log:**

```
RestClient.put "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/folder-name/file.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=xxx&Expires=xxx&Signature=xxx", 246572 byte(s) length, "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Content-Length"=>"246572", "Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data; boundary=183013"
```

**Response:**

```
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:326:in `syswrite': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from /Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:326:in `do_write'
    from /Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:344:in `write'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [PresignedPost](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/PresignedPost.html)

```
form = bucket.presigned_post(:key => "photos/${filename}")
form.url.to_s        # => "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/"
form.fields          # => { "AWSAccessKeyId" => "...", ... }
form.url             # your signed url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply `PUT` a file on S3. Use the [`write`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html) API to do that:

```
s3_object.write(:file => "local-file.zip")
```

Comment: The use case here is that a pre-signed URL for a PUT request is given to another system. That system doesn't know about AWS creds. Is there a way for that system to upload a file to that PUT URL - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html